# Typo in "search is offline" message

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, spelling

There is a typo on the [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) placeholder page (the page it has when the search is down).

It currently says:

> Oh no! Search is currently offline.
>
> This is usually because we let the gerbils out for 10 seconds longer
>   than we should have, or are actively improving our search results and
>   needed to take things offline while we re-index this site. Hang tight
>   and we'll return search to you as soon as possible. While you want,
>   consider checking out our search tips (who knows, maybe we just added
>   a new one).
>
> For the moment, you can try your search in Google:
>   http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com/questions
>   render_template

The last sentence starts with "While you want". I think it should say "While you wait"

Comment: Where ? I see neither want or wait

Comment: Try to get a screenshot if you can.

Comment: Oops. I rushed it a little. I've made an edit. Would you still like a screenshot?

Comment: Yes, it should be wait.

Comment: it's question-like , "while you want" you answer, how you want

Comment: @xsi then shouldnt it be 'if you want' ?

Comment: What? A typo that doesn't involve S's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well damn, that was supposed to be placeholder text I typed hastily while losing my mind not intended to go out.  Still, fixed the typo in the next build until that gets revised.